# AWS java project creation error

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have installed aws plugins from http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse.
While creating aws java project, next and finish buttons are not enabling. 
While opening eclipse, I am getting below errors. 
Couldn't read regions file, 
Failed to cache regions file, 
Unable to check status of AWS SDK for Java download and Unable to refresh security groups: Unable to execute HTTP request: peer not authenticated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is,your AWS SDK is not installed and updated properly . Just click on >Help in eclipse and then click on >Installation Details and from that reinstall AWS Eclipse plugin .

Please make sure that url of plugin is appropriated for your eclipse version.

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a new workspace and you will be good to go.
Let know if the problem still persists.